# Variable won't be filtered correctly

Tags: ansible

what am I doing wrong?
I use below task to get all defined log_dirs of a host. Those information are stored in a fact, which is a dict and this works like a charm.

```
- name: get all_log_dirs
  set_fact:
    all_log_dirs="{{ (all_log_dirs|default({})) | combine( { item.key:vars[item.key] } ) }}"
  with_dict: "{{ vars }}"
  when: item.key is search('^((?!splunk).)*_log_dir')
```

Here the appropriate output:

> ```
>  "ansible_facts": {
>      "all_log_dirs": {
>         "springboot_server_log_dir": "{{ server_deployment_dir }}/logs"}
> ```

But the problem is, if I now want to use the new dict for e. g.:

```
- name: create symlink for splunk if not present
  file:
    src: "{{ item.value }}"
    dest: "{{ splunk_log_dir }}/{{ item.key | regex_replace('_server_log_dir|_log_dir') | regex_replace('eap','jboss-eap') }}"
    state: link
  with_dict: "{{ all_log_dirs }}"
```

I only get:

> ```
> failed: [...] (item={'value': u'{{ server_deployment_dir }}/logs', 'key': u'springboot_server_log_dir'}) => {
> "changed": false,
> "invocation": {
>     "module_args": {
>         "dest": "/somedir/springboot",
>         "path": "/somedir/springboot",
>         "src": "{{ server_deployment_dir }}/logs",
>         "state": "link",
>     }
> },
> "msg": "src file does not exist, use \"force=yes\" if you really want to create the link: /somedir/{{ server_deployment_dir }}/logs",
> "path": "/somedir/springboot",
> "src": "{{ server_deployment_dir }}/logs",
> "state": "absent"
> ```
>
> }

Why isn't {{ server_deployment_dir }} filtered correctly by Ansible?
Even I change src to dest and the way around, it won't work, because the variable isn't being filtered.

The value of {{ server_deployment_dir }} is of course host specific and is sth like /opt/applicationXY/appDeployDir

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `vars` object. Period.

It is **internal** variable storage intended for under-the-hood usage.

When Ansible template engine detects `vars` access, it stops further templating chain!

Example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    myvar1: hello
    myvar2: world
    myvar3: "{{ myvar2 }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ myvar1 }} {{ myvar3 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ vars['myvar1'] }} {{ vars['myvar3'] }}"
```

Result:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "hello world"
}

TASK [debug] ***************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "hello {{ myvar2 }}"
}
```

**Update**: if you utterly need to access variable trough vars object, there's `vars` lookup available in Ansible 2.5; and it templates values as usual:

E.g.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('vars','myvar1') }} {{ lookup('vars','myvar3') }}"
```

results to `hello world` in the context of my previous example.

Comment: Excellent!! , Thank you.