# Explanation of behaviour of Ansible Playbook variables defined in vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am fairly new to Ansible and today while writing a new playbook I came across some behaviour I can't explain. I have been through the documentation and done my best Google-Fu, but I can't seem to find the answer.

The behaviour relates to variables defined in a playbook's "var" section and their lack of expansion into proper values when using other variables or arithmetic.

Take an example playbook with "static" values in vars:

```
--- # Test playbook vars
- hosts: 'all'
connection: ssh
gather_facts: false
vars:
    - max_size_bytes: 10240

tasks:
- name: debug!
  debug:
      msg: |
         "max_size_bytes: {{max_size_bytes}}"
         "vars:           {{vars['max_size_bytes']}}"
```

This outputs:

```
# ansible-playbook -i host1, test_vars.yml

PLAY [all] *************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug!] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {}

MSG:

"max_size_bytes: 10240"
"vars:           10240"
```

Which is exactly what I would expect.

However, let's say I want to calculate that `10240` number dynamically:

```
--- # Test playbook vars
- hosts: 'all'
connection: ssh
gather_facts: false
vars:
    - max_size_bytes: "{{10 * 1024}}"

tasks:
- name: debug!
  debug:
      msg: |
         "max_size_bytes: {{max_size_bytes}}"
         "vars:           {{vars['max_size_bytes']}}"
```

And the new result is:

```
# ansible-playbook -i host1, test_vars.yml

PLAY [all] *************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug!] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {}

MSG:

"max_size_bytes: 10240"
"vars:           {{10 * 1024}}"
```

I get a similar output if I try to use another variable within the assignment. I came across this issue when I wanted to allow a playbook user to quick change some settings, without requiring them to calculate anything. For example:

```
vars:
    - max_size_in_megabytes: 100 #change me if required
    - max_size_bytes: "{{max_size_in_megabytes * 1024 * 1024}}"
```

But this didn't work as I expected, as above.

In some places the variable is expanded correctly and gives the result I would expect (i.e. the calculated value). At other times, it seems the variable is not expanded and is treated as a string as per the output for `vars['max_size_bytes']`.

- What is the reason for this behaviour? Variable expansion and calculated values seem to work elsewhere in a playbook - why not for pre-defined variables?
- If this behaviour is considered normal, what is the proper way of creating global/reusable variables that may need to be calculated on the fly?

**UPDATE**

I realise there may be some confusion as to what my issue actually is. That's my fault.

To try and explain better, take a look at another example:

```
--- # Test playbook vars
 - hosts: 'localhost'
   connection: local
   gather_facts: false
   vars:
       - multiplier: 10 #change me as required
       - some_value: 300
       - max_size_dynamic: "{{10 * 20}}"
       - max_size_static: 200

   tasks:
   - set_fact:
       is_bigger_dynamic: "{{some_value > max_size_dynamic}}"
       is_bigger_static: "{{some_value > max_size_static}}"

   - name: debug!
     debug:
         msg: |
            multiplier:          {{multiplier}}
            some_value           {{some_value}}

            Is {{some_value}} bigger than {{max_size_static}}?
            is_bigger_static:   {{is_bigger_static}}     <-- hooray

            Is {{some_value}} bigger than {{max_size_dynamic}}?
            is_bigger_dynamic:   {{is_bigger_dynamic}}   <-- woops!
```

When running this playbook, you can see that the value of the conditional clauses in the `set_fact` task differs based on how a variable is created in `vars`.

Output:

```
PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug!] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {}

MSG:

multiplier:          10
some_value           300

Is 300 bigger than 200?
is_bigger_static:   True     <-- hooray

Is 300 bigger than 200?
is_bigger_dynamic:   False   <-- woops!
```

The conditionals are checking the same expression: `300 > 200`, but if the value 200 is derived from another expression in `vars` the condition is wrong.

I suspect in the case of `{{some_value > max_size_dynamic}}` the variable isn't being expanded (much like using `vars['name\]` as mentioned in the comments). So it looks like the conditional ends up being `{{some_value > "{{10 * 20}}"}}`.

Is this expected behaviour with `set_fact`? Is there anything I can do to allow expressions in `vars` which can be further used in `set_fact` tasks?

This is running the latest version of Ansible on MacOS High Sierra:

```
# ansible --version
ansible 2.5.0
  config file = /Users/xxx/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/Users/xxx/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.5.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.14 (default, Apr  9 2018, 16:44:39) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)]
```

Comment: I answered this two hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49817222/2795592

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov you state not to use vars at all. What is the alternative for setting variables for the whole playbook that may be dynamic and/or rely on other variables already declared?

Comment: I didn't say that. I said not to use `vars` object to access variables inside Jinja2 expressions. Still you may/should use `vars` keyword to define play/task level variables in playbooks.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I may not have been completely clear about my issue. It's not about using `vars` directly, but how other tasks seem to not expand variables. See my update at the end of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your update to the question is completely different to original post.

And the issue with update part is this: [Why a string in always "greater than" a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552949/why-a-string-in-always-greater-than-a-number)

Just do the type casting:

```
- set_fact:
    is_bigger_dynamic: "{{some_value > max_size_dynamic | int }}"
    is_bigger_static: "{{some_value > max_size_static }}"
```

In your case `some_value` and `max_size_static` are numbers, but `max_size_dynamic` is a string (you can't make simple integer outside of `{{...}}` in ansible – only strings/booleans/lists/dictionaries).